# JSON object. Can't retrieve data in template. Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Template helper:

```
Template.userLoggedIn.helpers({
    stream: function() {
        return ReactiveMethod.call("checkApi", function(err, results) {
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'); //nothing
            res = JSON.parse(results.content); // nothing
            return res
        });
    }
```

In my template:

```
{{#with stream }}
    {{this}} //Object object
{{/with}}
```

If i'm trying:

```
{{#with stream }}
        {{this.livestream}} //Undefined
  {{/with}}
```

My Meteor.Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
        checkApi: function () {
            this.unblock();
            re = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/uccleague")
            return re;
        }
    });
```

How i can get access to this json object?
Return of a calling method (JSON) here:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1ae1eaaf7a4e942bd4a0728517b10779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReactiveMethod](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method) doesn't take a callback as its last argument (avoiding the callback is the entire point of the package). You need to use it like this:

```
Template.userLoggedIn.helpers({
  stream: function() {
    return ReactiveMethod.call('checkApi');
  }
});
```

Which implies that's you'd do the JSON parsing in your method like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
  checkApi: function () {
    this.unblock();
    try {
      var result = Meteor.http.call('GET', '...');
      return JSON.parse(result.content);
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
});
```